# Css div not working properly when hovered in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I have made a pricing table not using `<table>` tags but with `<div>` tags.Its is working perfectly in Firefox but not working properly in chrome.When you hover a div in chrome some how the z-index property don't work.Here's the fiddle for it
 http://jsfiddle.net/JmLRe/

Here is the image when not hovered or in normal state.

[image]

Here when it is hovered in Firefox.

[image]

But here where the problem lies in chrome.

[image]

Please tell me what i am doing wrong in css.

Comment: As this is an actual table, this is one of the rare times that the 'table' tag is appropriate. I haven't gone into your CSS indetail, but I suspect that if you transferred it to those tags, your CSS will sort itself out, as a grid is the table tag's natural state.

Comment: see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/JmLRe/2/ . now its working

Comment: Off-topic - I think the pricing table looks pretty sweet! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution by James isn't really working well for me. It only fixes the `premium` section.

Adding a `position: relative;` to `.table-item:hover` seems to work for all sections:

```
.table-item:hover{
    position:relative; /* Added this */
    transform:scale(1.08);
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.08);
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
#premium:hover{
    position:relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```